# Mongodb : value not beign saved in db , but present in console.log of schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloudinary

im new to mongo db , im trying to save the url of an image into mongo db but the value isn't beign saved.  But the url is present in the schema when i do console.log
before .save() ;

```
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.photo.path, {  folder: 'products' }, function (err, image) {
        if (err) { 
            return res.status(400).json({
                error : "Unable to upload the image"
            })
        }
        console.log(product.photo);
        console.log(image.url);
        product.photo = image.url;
        console.log(product.photo);
        console.log(product);

    });
```

output of `console.log(product);` :

```
{ sold: 0,
  _id: 5edc1830887d5801c88420d9,
  name: 'ider',
  description: 'classic prod',
  price: 10,
  category: 5ed9258ae973f42bbcbef42b,
  stock: 27,
  createdAt: 2020-06-06T22:26:56.136Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-06-06T22:26:56.136Z,
  __v: 0,
  photo:   'http://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/v1591482420/products/iwsutsgezodvvbyvopnf.png' }
```

saving of product :

```
//save to db
product.save((err, prod) => {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error : "Saving of product failed"
        })
    }
    res.json(prod);
})
```

response:

```
{
    "sold": 0,
    "_id": "5edc1830887d5801c88420d9",
    "name": "ider",
    "description": "classic prod",
    "price": 10,
    "category": "5ed9258ae973f42bbcbef42b",
    "stock": 27,
    "createdAt": "2020-06-06T22:26:56.136Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T22:26:56.136Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

how photo is defined is schema : `photo: String`

full schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 2000
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true
    },
    category: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: true
    },
    stock: {
      type: Number
    },
    sold: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    photo: String
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

also i checked with robo 3t and there is not photo value in the db

Comment: can you insert the full schema of your collection please ?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT done

Comment: Are you saving the product after uploading image, in its callback? Looks like an async issue.

Comment: @tbking thanks , solved ... was saving the product out of callback :) , thanks again , if you can give me real answer so i can accept it

Comment: glad it helped! Added the answer @imOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saving of product is happening before the asynchronous uploading could complete (as confirmed in the comments).

Saving the product in the image upload callback should work:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.photo.path, {  folder: 'products' }, function (err, image) {
    if (err) { 
        return res.status(400).json({
                error : "Unable to upload the image"
        })
    }
    //save to db
    product.save((err, prod) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error : "Saving of product failed"
            })
        }
        res.json(prod);
    })
 });
```